How to change the location of default folder for QGIS profiles?
Is it possible to change the location of QGIS Active Profiles Folder?
A quick Google suggested that creating a new environment variable QGIS_USER_PROFILE with variable value being the path to the profile folder should work but for some reason that does not work.


Did you restart QGIS as requested? And does the path contain profile data? Also, how do you know it didn't work?

I did restart QGIS multiple times, the path does contain profile data. I know it didn't work because the profile name says my name and if it did work it should have changed to my co-workers name. I thought it might be an issue with the location of the new profile folder being on a network drive, however, changing the plugin location worked with the same network drive.
